# How can i input this formula into my c++ program?

Tags: c++, formula

> Wind Chill = 35.74 + 0.6215T - 35.75(V^0.16) + 0.4275T(V^0.16)

I need the correct way to input the above formula into my program. I currently have the following and it's giving me a crazy number:

```
WindChill = ((35.74 + (0.6215 * temperature))
    - (35.75 * pow(windSpeed, 0.16))
    + (0.4275 * temperature * pow(windSpeed, 0.16)));
```

I am a beginner programmer, C++ is my first language I am learning so I would appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: could you specify input values and the output you get, and output you expect?

Comment: Are all those variables declared as floats/doubles, or do you have ints lurking around?

Comment: BTW, you don't need any of those brackets, except to call the pow function

Comment: They are all doubles, WindChill, temperature, and windSpeed.

Comment: @0723kas , what about your input,output and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify by removing parenthesis.

```
double wind_chill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * T - 35.75 * pow(V, 0.16) + 0.4275 * T * pow(V, 0.16);
```

But in this case you calculate the power two times. A better way is :

```
double pow_v = pow(V, 0.16);
double wind_chill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * T - 35.75 * pow_v + 0.4275 * T * pow_v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. And if you are using your own power function then rather then again and againcalling that method you can store it in some variable. That will be good for efficiency as well as readability.

```
double windPower = pow(windspeed, 0.16);
WindChill = (35.74 + (0.6215 * temp) - (35.75 * windPower ) + (0.4275 * temp * windPower ))
```

And your power function ( if you want to define it ) goes like this:-

```
int pow(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    if( y == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (y%2 == 0)
        return power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);
    else
        return x*power(x, y/2)*power(x, y/2);

}
```

This is for integers ( As I was able to test it quickly ).

Comment: They are trying to raise `windspeed` to the `0.16` power. Why would you write a `pow` function that takes an `unsigned int` power?

Comment: I have just given example of int as I was able to test it quickly. I believe replicating it for double is not much difficult task

Comment: ... or just use `std::pow`.

Comment: yeah that's always at your disposal. That's why I said in case you want to write your own power function.

Answer (score 0):

If you compute by hand, using the same data, does it give you the same crazy number, or the correct answer? If you get the same crazy number, maybe you need to convert some of your numbers to the correct units, eg temperature should probably be in Kelvin rather than Celsius or Farhenheit.

(This should have been a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet...)